# IP Table Firewall

Tags: iptables

I just had a simple question, well what should seem to be since I am very new to IP Tables. As far as questions I wanted to know if the rules I have set below are in the correct "order" because I heard that order counts, and I have a feeling something isn't quite right. If anybody can help me out with some organization, or if there is anything else you see, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo 1> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0:1 down

iptables -F
iptables -F -t nat 

ifconfig eth0 192.168.10.59 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.60.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default gw 192.168.10.1
echo nameserver 192.168.10.1 > /etc/resolv.conf

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.60.1/24 -j SNAT MASQUERADE 
(--to 192.168.10.59) not necessary

chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/rc.ip_forward
    /etc/rc.d/rc.ip_forward start

chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd
    /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd start

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP


iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.1/24 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.85 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT  -Outside Comp Mac Address
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT  -Outside Comp Mac Address
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.59.84 -p tcp --dport 22-j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT - m mac --mac-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT  -Inside Comp Mac Address
iptables -A OUTPUT - m mac --mac-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT  Inside Comp Mac Address
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

We can not tell you what is right and what is wrong simply by looking at your rules. Your rules need to be matched with your policy. A more accurate question can be written as: "*I need to make sure that all inbound ports are closed except ...*". However, I can say that you have a useless rule which will never match:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.85 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

because it comes after this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.1/24 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to set the policies first, then flush the chains, then create your new ruleset:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -F
iptables -F -t nat

iptables -A INPUT ...
...
```

Otherwise your ruleset might inadvertently turn open (for however brief a time).